# RXJS: How to get connect event? retrywhen: how to hook into execution?

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs, rxjs-observables, retrywhen

When Angular tries to connect, I want to show "Connecting". I can do it on first connect, but I don't know how to do it when using retryWhen(). I need to hook into the actual execution and then do:

```
this.connectionStatus = "Connecting"
```

Current code:

```
    this.connectionStatus = "Connecting";

    let socket = new WebSocketSubject(..);

    this.socket
      .pipe(retryWhen(errors =>
        errors.pipe(
          tap(val => {
            console.log("Retry in 10 sec", val);
          }),
          delay(10000)
        )))
      .subscribe(..);
```

Comment: doesn't retryWhen work ?

Comment: The method gets called instantly but the reconnect is in 10 seconds. I want to set status to "connecting" when it is really connecting, not in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the status after delay. `retryWhen` expect you to return an observable and when this observable emits it'll start retrying connecting i.e start retrying after `delay`

```
  errors.pipe(
          tap(val => {
            console.log("Retry in 10 sec", val);
          }),
          delay(10000),
          tap(()=>this.connectionStatus = "Connecting"
)
        )))
```

Comment: Thanks. I dont know why it works that way, but it works. If you have time, please add an explanation.